# Remove shared file from MyDrive

Tags: google-sheets

I clicked on a Google Spreadsheet link in a stackoverflow question.  The spreadsheet was copied to MyDrive but now I can not delete or remove it.

In the past I simply made a copy of the shared spreadsheet and then would delete the original shared link.

Selecting the file from MyDrive and hitting the delete key doesn't work.  From the contect menu the "remove" option is dimmed.

Any suggestions.

Comment: If you go to the sharing settings of the document, are you listed as the owner of the file?

Comment: There is no owner but there is creator and it's not me.  It says "You do not have permission to view sharing information for this item"

Comment: If you go to `Details` by going to `3 dots` > `view details` > `Details` > `Location`, under type do you see `Google Sheets Shortcut`? Or have you try to search for the file under `Share with me` to see if you can remove it from there?

Comment: Or by any changes under `Storage used` in details, does it mention that the file storage usage is under a domain?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether your situation is the same as mine, for example, as one proposal, when you manually move the relevant file in the "shared with me" directory to the trash box on your Google Drive with your browser, can the file be removed in your situation? In my situation, this could be done. In this case, please directly move manually the file to the trash box by drag and drop, because the trash box button on the file is disabled. I'm not sure whether this is not the direct solution to your issue. So, I proposed this as a comment. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, that worked.  Thanks.  It doen't show up in `Trash` either.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. Unfortunately, when the file is publicly shared with the shared drive and the file is accessed by the browser with a logged-in Google account, such a file is created in the shared with me directory. That file has no Trash button. So, I always manually move it to the trash box.

Comment: But, I couldn't confirm that my situation is the same as yours. So, I proposed it as a comment. But from your reply, I understood that your situation was the same as mine. I think that this information will be useful for a lot of users. So, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for a lot of users. Of course, I can do it if you permit.

Comment: @Tanaike, you go ahead and I'll give you credit for the answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted it as an answer. Please confirm it. I would like to believe that this can be achieved by Drive service and Drive API in the future update on the Google side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation is as follows.

- You accessed a file on the publicly shared file with the shared drive using your browser with a logged-in to your Google account.

In this case, the accessed file is shown in your "shared with me" folder. The file has no Trash button. And also, this file cannot be removed even when Drive service (DriveApp) and Drive API are used, because of no permission.

When I got such a file, I always move the file manually to the trash box on my browser. By this, the file can be removed from "shared with me" folder.

In this case, please directly move manually the file to the trash box by drag and drop, because the trash box button on the file is disabled. By this, the file can be removed from "shared with me" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue, and I know why is happening. However, I haven't found an option to remove the file. (It might not be possible).

If the owner of the file stored the Google Sheet inside a `Share Drive`, and selected the option `Editors can change permissions and share` as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893#zippy=%2Cprevent-others-from-sharing-your-files); the users that access to the file will not be able to access to the sharing permissions of it, and get the message:

[image: Who has access]

Which is essentially the only way to remove yourself from the sharing permissions.

I even try to remove the permission with the Google Drive API, using the `File ID`, and the permissionId = `anyoneWithLink`, but I gt the error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The authenticated user does not have the required access to delete the permission.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The authenticated user does not have the required access to delete the permission.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "cannotDeletePermission"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, the only way to remove that file from your Google Drive, will be to request the owner of the file to remove you from the permissions by stop sharing the file with anyone with the link.

[image: anyone with the link]

In the worst case scenario, you can submit a [Developer product feedback](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/support#developer_product_feedback) to request an option to do so.

[Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) made a similar comment in his profile regarding this, too.

#### Update:

I tested @Tanike solution, and it works for me. Just drag and drop the file, and it will be removed from Google Drive. I change my answer as a community Wiki, since the answer was provided by someone else.