How to programmatically remove my access to a shared Google Drive file when I am not the owner?
Context:
I am trying to use the Google Drive API to remove my own access to files that have been shared with me. My goal is to stop having access to these files entirely. I am not the owner of these files, but I have been added as a collaborator (either as an editor, viewer, or commenter).
What I've Tried:
I've written a script using Google Apps Script that attempts to remove my permissions using the permissions.delete method from the Google Drive API. Here's the relevant portion of the script:
function removeMyselfFromAllFiles() {
  const activeUserEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var pageToken = null;

  do {
    var result = Drive.Files.list({
      q: "trashed = false", 
      pageSize: 100,         
      pageToken: pageToken,  
      corpora: "allDrives",  
      includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
      supportsAllDrives: true, 
      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, permissions)"
    });

    if (result.files && result.files.length > 0) {
      var files = result.files;

      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < file.permissions.length; j++) {
          var permission = file.permissions[j];
          if (permission.emailAddress === activeUserEmail) {
            var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + file.id + '/permissions/' + permission.id;
            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
              method: 'delete',
              headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
              },
              muteHttpExceptions: true
            });

            if (response.getResponseCode() === 204) {
              Logger.log("Successfully removed myself from: " + file.name);
            } else {
              Logger.log("Failed to remove myself from: " + file.name + " - Response: " + response.getContentText());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    pageToken = result.nextPageToken;

  } while (pageToken);
}

The Problem:
When running the script, I often encounter the following error:
Failed to remove myself from: [File Name] - Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I understand that the error occurs because I don't have sufficient permissions to modify the sharing settings of the file. However, my goal is simply to remove my access to the file so that it no longer appears in my Google Drive, and neither my email appears as a collaborator on the file.
My Questions:

Is there a way to programmatically remove my access to a file when I am not the owner, using the Google Drive API?

Additional Context:

I want to automate the process for multiple files and avoid manually changing permissions on each one.
I’m looking for a scalable solution that can handle many files automatically without manual intervention.

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, is this thread related to the answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76264143 If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

How was the file shared with you? Are you using an account managed by you(like having a domain from gmail.com or Workspace Individual) or managed by someone else aka Google Workspace account. Is your account a member of a Google Group used to share files?

Hi @Tanaike ,
Thanks for your suggestion!However, I think that solution might not fully address my situation. While moving the file to the trash will remove it from the "Shared with me" section, my goal is also to automatically remove myself as a collaborator.
From what I understand, simply clicking "Remove file" might not revoke my access as a collaborator, and the file could still reappear if I’m still listed as a collaborator. Do you know if removing the file in this way also removes my permission as a collaborator, or would I need to take additional steps to ensure that happens?

Hi! @Wicket The file was shared with me by directly adding my email as a collaborator. I'm using an account that's managed by me, not a Google Workspace account. I’m not a member of any Google Group that was used to share the file.

In some situations, it's impossible for a user to remove themselves as editor, viewer or commenter by using Google Apps Script Drive Service and the Drive API. In some cases, the option is to use the Google Drive user interface to drag the file to the Trash / Bin. In some cases, it might be necessary to consider blocking other users from sharing files with them (for details, see Block & unblock people in Google Drive). This might be automated by using a tool for automating user interface actions.
Regarding your current script, I suggest you enhance it to identify how the file was shared with you whenever possible.

As mentioned above, the Google Apps Script Drive Service and the Drive API do not have a single method to remove a user as an editor, commenter or viewer that works in all possible cases. Below are some ways where a user can't be removed as an editor, commenter and viewer:

Anyone with the link.
Anyone from the domain (for Google Workspace-managed accounts).
Files shared with a group from Google Groups or Google Workspace.
Sharing setting inherited from a folder
Sharing settings inherited from a Shared Drive


Hi @Wicket !
If the Google Drive API is not able to fully address my use case, it sounds like blocking and then unblocking the users who most commonly share files with me could be a potential workaround.
Would this approach, in addition to removing the files from the "Shared with me" section, also effectively remove me as a collaborator if the file owner is one of the users I blocked? I'm curious if this method could serve as a way to automate the process of stopping access to shared files, even if it doesn't directly use the API.
Thanks for your help and insights!

@Vladimirzb I don't know how Block and Unblock work internally, so I can't tell if your email address will be removed from the file shared settings, hidden, etc. for the files that are already shared with you. As the feature is named "block" I assume that this is intended to avoid using the sharing feature for spamming users.
